# How can I filter an array with 3 dimensions in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I know this is one of the easiest task in numpy but I don't get it. I have an array:

```
import numpy as np

u1 = np.array([[[-2.04853845, -1.47283101,  1.        ],
                [-2.05009646, -1.46780913,  1.        ],
                [-2.05165539, -1.46278426,  1.        ]],
               [[-4.94165412,  7.8524744 ,  1.        ],
                [ 0.94540647,   0.86456925,  1.       ],
                [-4.94916228,  7.87667525,  1.        ]]])
```

u1 is a summary of the matrix. The real size of the matrix is:

```
u1.shape
(813, 1200, 3)
```

I want to get all the values where the first and the second element of last array (last dimension) is between 0 and 1, so I get and array containing boolean so I can index another array with the same shape.

I bet this is a duplicate question, but I didn't find it. Thanks

Comment: What did you tried so far? Did you read numpy documentation?

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't find what I needed it. It seems like I need to use np.logical_and(), thanks anyway

Comment: Numpy documentation is excellent, see the "indexing" one in your case: https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/contents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the following:

```py
import numpy as np

u1 = np.array([[[-2.04853845, -1.47283101,  1.],
                [-2.05009646, -1.46780913,  1.],
                [-2.05165539, -1.46278426,  1.]],
               [[-4.94165412,  7.8524744,   1.],
                [ 0.94540647,  0.86456925,  1.],
                [-4.94916228,  7.87667525,  1.]]])

np.logical_and(u1[:,:,0:2]>0, u1[:,:,0:2]<1)
array([[[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True,  True],
        [False, False]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the elements and compare against your values:

```
import numpy as np

u1 = np.array([[[-2.04853845, -1.47283101,  1.        ],
                [-2.05009646, -1.46780913,  1.        ],
                [-2.05165539, -1.46278426,  1.        ]],
               [[-4.94165412,  7.8524744 ,  1.        ],
                [ 0.94540647,   0.86456925,  1.       ],
                [-4.94916228,  7.87667525,  1.        ]]])

first = (u1[:, :, 0] > 0) * (u1[:, :, 0] < 1)
second = (u1[:, :, 1] > 0) * (u1[:, :, 1] < 1)

condition = first * second
# Condition is:
# [[False False False]
# [False  True False]]
```

Then extract the rows you are interested in:

```
values = u1[condition]

print(values)
# Prints:
# [[0.94540647 0.86456925 1.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function checking first 2 elements of a row:

```
def myfunc(row):
    return np.logical_and(row[0:2] >= 0, row[0:2] <= 1).all()
```

Then apply it to every 1-D slice along the last dimension (let's call it
a *row*):

```
np.apply_along_axis( myfunc, axis=-1, arr=u1 )
```

The result, for your sample data, is:

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])
```